# Getting -Wincompatible-pointer-types for struct pointer warning when compiling

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, compiler-warnings

I'm following along with [this](https://youtu.be/2Ti5yvumFTU?list=TLPQMjUwODIwMjKuiGOf27U0nQ&t=1272) tutorial to learn about external chaining in Hashtables in C. I find that I get the following error when compiling with `gcc --std=c99`:

```
warning: assignment to "person *" {aka 'struct <anonymous> *'} from incompatible pointer type 'struct person *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
101 | tmp = tmp->next;

warning: assignment to "person *" {aka 'struct <anonymous> *'} from incompatible pointer type 'struct person *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
112 | p->next = hash_table[index];

warning: assignment to "person *" {aka 'struct <anonymous> *'} from incompatible pointer type 'struct person *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
121 | tmp = tmp->next;

warning: assignment to "person *" {aka 'struct <anonymous> *'} from incompatible pointer type 'struct person *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
132 | tmp = tmp->next;

warning: assignment to "person *" {aka 'struct <anonymous> *'} from incompatible pointer type 'struct person *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
136 | hash_table[index] = tmp->nxt;
```

I find that this occurs only with the `next` pointer for the person struct:

```
typedef struct {
   char name[TABLE_SIZE];
   int age;
   //...
   struct person *next;
} person;
```

For functions like these:

```
void print_table(){
   for (int i=0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++0 {
       if (hash_table[i] == NULL) {
           printf("\t%i\t---n\n",i);
       }
       else {
            printf("\t%i\t",i);
            person *tmp = hash_table[i];
            while (tmp != NULL) {
                printf("%s -", tmp->name);
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
            printf("\n");
       }
   }
}

bool hash_table_insert(person *p) {             
    if (p == NULL) return false;                
    int index = hash(p->name);
    p->next = hash_table[index];
    hash_table[index] = p;
    return true; 
}
```

The hashtable's output is correct so clearly it works fine but it gets these warnings. I did not get these warnings until implementing the chaining technique. I'm inclined to believe it has something to do with the addition of `struct person *next;` , or at least it's usage. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where do you define `struct person`? In the code you show you only define a type `person` but not `struct person`.

Comment: If you look at the video you linked, the first thing was to change `typedef struct {` to `typedef struct person {` You did not do that same change

Comment: Thanks @Gerhardh for the simple explanation. Can't believe I missed that, still learning everyday! Thanks for the welcome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typedef declaration

```
typedef struct {
   char name[TABLE_SIZE];
   int age;
   //...
   struct person *next;
} person;
```

declares an unnamed structure with the typedef name `person`, and  this record within the unnamed structure

```
   struct person *next;
```

introduces an incomplete type specifier `struct person`.

Thus `person` and `struct person` are two different type specifiers.

You could, for example

```
typedef struct person person;

struct person {
   char name[TABLE_SIZE];
   int age;
   //...
   struct person *next;
};
```

or

```
typedef struct person {
   char name[TABLE_SIZE];
   int age;
   //...
   struct person *next;
} person;
```

Answer (score 1):

An *anonymous* struct is a struct without a *tag*.
Give your struct a *tag* and then use `struct person` everywhere.

And don't bother with typedefs for structs. All they do is save you from typing `struct` in a few places, like declarations.

```
struct person {
   char name[TABLE_SIZE];
   int age;
   //...
   struct person *next;
};
...
struct person *tmp = hash_table[i];
```

On another note, functions taking no arguments should be declared with a `(void)` argument list, otherwise they indicate an *unspecified but fixed* argument list. In particular, in C, something like

```
int foo();
```

is **not** a prototype! It's an old-style (K&R C) function declaration from the age when C did not have the `void` keyword.